# OneNote backslash character codes?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, character-encoding

Where do I find a reference page for oneNote which lists all the character codes for symbols you can type using back slash on one note?

E.g. you can type \in and you get the set notation symbol ∈. How do I get the rest? I tried \subset but it only gives me the proper subset symbol.

Appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem in OneNote too, and through some experimentation I found that if you want the subset symbol (i.e. the underlined one), you need to type:

```
\subseteq
```

Simply typing \subset gives you the proper subset symbol, i.e. the one without the underline. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

#### How do I get the rest?

OneNote 2013 uses the same equation editor as Word 2007/2010.

> [image]

There are many more in the linked pdf.

Source [The Word 2007/2010 Equation Editor](https://mathiho.sitehost.iu.edu/doc/equation-editor-shortcut-commands.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't appear to have the subset symbol with the horizontal bar though.

Comment: There are many more in the linked document...

Comment: Ok, I checked the doc before and didn't see a the symbol with the underbar. I tried to use the underwear function with a \subset in it, and that did the trick.

Although, I can't seem to be able to create a not in subset symbol...

Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

How do I get the rest?

You can use [UnicodeMath (pdf)](https://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v3.1.pdf) or for a more condensed version [The Word 2007/2010 Equation Editor (pdf)](https://mathiho.sitehost.iu.edu/doc/equation-editor-shortcut-commands.pdf)